# getting error for file.load (file) method when the path has \

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, pdfbox

I have a file which I am trying to read the content from.

**Code tried:**

```
String userDir = System.getProperty("user.home")+"\\Downloads";

               //Loading an existing document

            String s=userDir+"\\PDFStatement.pdf";


              File file = new File(s);

             //File file = new File(s);
               System.out.println("file"+file);
              PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(file);// this is where I am getting error

              //Instantiate PDFTextStripper class
              PDFTextStripper pdfStripper = new PDFTextStripper();

              //Retrieving text from PDF document
              String text = pdfStripper.getText(document);
              System.out.println(text);

              //Closing the document
              document.close();

        }
```

**Error :**

```
java.io.IOException: Error: Expected an integer type, actual='statement'
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.BaseParser.readInt(BaseParser.java:1622)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.PDFParser.parseObject(PDFParser.java:531)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.PDFParser.parse(PDFParser.java:188)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument.load(PDDocument.java:1187)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument.load(PDDocument.java:1154)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument.load(PDDocument.java:1125)
```

Same code works when I pass the same file path with / as

```
File file = new File("C:/abc/abc/abc/PDFStatement.pdf");
```

I am using pdfbox 1.8

Thanks.

Comment: Please try using 2.0.19.

Comment: What does the "println" output show? I'm wondering because the exception message suggests that this isn't a PDF file, but a text file containing the text "statement". I suspect you accidentally overwrote your PDF file with the name of the file.

Comment: can you please explain "I suspect you accidentally overwrote your PDF file with the name of the file".The file downloaded as "PDFStaement.pdf" and has relevant content

Comment: The parser mentions the text "statement", your file has "statement" in its name, that is a weird coincidence. Maybe open your "PDF file" with NOTEPAD++ to see what is in it? It should start with "%PDF 1.". Btw from looking at the exception lines, you are using an 1.8 version (probably 1.8.0) that is from around 2013. The current 1.8 version is 1.8.16. You should use old versions only for software archeology.

Comment: I am downloading the file as part of test .downloaded file has name "PDFStatement.pdf"

Comment: Also checked on notepad++ as suggested .first line is %PDF-1.2

Comment: Have you tried to use a newer version?

Comment: @Tilman Hausherr Thanks  .After changing the pdfbox to 1.8.16 and fontbox to 1.5 .it worked. Thanks a lot for the help.
Though have another issue related to it  so will ask in another question

Comment: These must be the same versions!

Comment: same version was not working for me

Comment: This is really weird - I suspect that you had several versions in your classpath.